# How to remove rows from a dataset based on matching unique values from another dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have here a training and testing dataset. The training set has more **unique** categorical values than the testing set and I would like to filter out those rows from the training set that are actually exclusive to only the training set.

For example, let's take the categorical columns `Frequency` and `PaymentMode`. The training set has 4 unique values for frequency and 11 for the latter. However, for the testing set, I have 3 and 10 unique values respectively (1 less for each column).

```py
for col in data.columns:
    if data[col].dtype == "object":
        print(col)
        print(data[col].unique())
        print('')

Frequency
['Monthly' 'Quatrly' 'Half Yearly' 'BI-Monthly']

PaymentMode
['PDC_E' 'PDC' 'Direct Debit' 'Billed' 'ECS' 'Auto Debit' 'SI Reject'
 'ECS Reject' 'Cheque' 'PDC Reject' 'Escrow']


for col in valData.columns:
    if valData[col].dtype == "object":
        print(col)
        print(valData[col].unique())
        print('')

Frequency
['Monthly' 'Quatrly' 'Half Yearly']

PaymentMode
['PDC_E' 'PDC' 'Billed' 'Direct Debit' 'ECS' 'ECS Reject' 'SI Reject'
 'Cheque' 'Auto Debit' 'PDC Reject']
```

What I want is samples for 'Bi-Monthly' and 'Escrow' to be removed from the training set since these are exclusive only to it. I have tried this but with an error:

```py
data.loc[data[["Frequency", "PaymentMode"]].isin(valData[["Frequency", "PaymentMode"]])]

ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Is there another way in pandas without individually specifying which values to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a multi column for this case. A combination of two filter , asking both columns don't have factors not present in the test should work :

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency':np.random.choice(['Monthly','Quatrly','Half Yearly','BI-Monthly'],100),
'PaymentMode':np.random.choice(['Cheque','PDC Reject','Escrow'],100)})

valData = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency':np.random.choice(['Monthly','Quatrly','Half Yearly'],100),
'PaymentMode':np.random.choice(['Cheque','PDC Reject',],100)})

da = data[(data["Frequency"].isin(valData["Frequency"]) & data["PaymentMode"].isin(valData["PaymentMode"]))]

pd.crosstab(da['Frequency'],da['PaymentMode'])
Out[25]: 
PaymentMode  Cheque  PDC Reject
Frequency                      
Half Yearly       9           5
Monthly           9          11
Quatrly           7           6
```

Comment: Precise and elegant :)